# error when trying to execute pl/sql with callablestatement

Tags: oracle, plsql

I am having difficulties executing a pl/sql statement with jdbc`s callablestatement.
This is the error I'm getting:`PL/SQL: ORA-00933: SQL command not properly ended`

And this is the statement:

```
DECLARE
BEGIN
 IF ('XXX' <> 'XXX')
 THEN
    update XXX set XXX=1 where XXX='XXX' and XXX like 'XXX'

 END IF;
END;
/
```

It runs fine in Oracle sql developer. I have tried removing "/" and the semicolon behing "END", but it does not work. Get the same error now matter what I do. The values have been replaced with "XXX" for this post.

Do any of you wise guys have some helpful insight?

Answer (score 2):

1. Semicolon is missing after the `UPDATE` statement
2. As you have no variables declared, `DECLARE` keyword is optional
3. Be careful with `and XXX like 'XXX'`. using `Like` condition without wildcards is the same as using equality operator.
4. You might consider using [MERGE](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e26088/statements_9016.htm#i2081218) statement instead of this PL/SQL block.

Comment: Thanks. Nr.1 fixed it! :)